# Empty CHANGELOG.md

Tags: gitlab, changelog

in gitlab.ci I create a changelog with the command "curl --header "Authorization: Bearer **************" --data "version=2.5.0&from=v2.4.0&to=2.5 .0" "https://git.*********.ru/api/v4/projects/22/repository/changelog"". The file CHANGELOG.md is created, which says "No changes". Can you suggest what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [--trailer "Changelog"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-interpret-trailers) in your git commit messages:

> git commit -m "My change" --trailer "Changelog"

If you have such commits, you can get changelog data generated on the `repository/changelog` api call.

See the discussion here: [GitLab forum](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/changelog-generator-api-always-return-no-changes/65875)